# Angular: Proper way to implement a custom directive's visibility

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently working on a new custom directive which will transclude some HTML *around* the element you've called it on. This means however that if you have a `ng-show` directive as well on the element that the HTML would still be transcluded and hence shown.

A working example of the directive is located on [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvWfTYym2F8XXKvwbM0v?p=preview).

I'd like to counter this, by making my custom directive respond to `ng-show` but I can see a big problem with this approach as `ng-show` will hide or show the whole element it is called on.

On the other hand, I don't really like having a lot of custom directives each defining their own `visible` properties as an alternative to `ng-show`.

A third option would be to support both? This would allow me to switch of specific directives on an element as well as hiding it completely with `ng-show`

Has anyone got good recommendations on which approach I would have to take here? This is not a solitary case, we have a lot of custom directives of which we'll need to control visibility.

To summarize, these are the three options I'm thinking of:

1. Let custom directive respond to ng-show
2. Define own visibility control per custom directive (which could use ng-show underlying)
3. Support option 1 and 3

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you transclude HTML from around the directive? AFAIK you can only transclude the element the directive is called on or its children. And if you could share some code it would be helpful to understand your problem better.

Comment: You can take a template and then put the transcluded element somewhere inside of that element. I'll see if I can provide a working Plunkr

Comment: Would a solution using `ng-if` be acceptable?

Comment: @Anzeo I know that you can control where the transcluded content goes with `ng-transclude`, maybe I understood you wrong in your question. I thought you meant that a parent or sibling is also transcluded not just the element itself.

Comment: I've updated my question with a Plunkr. As you can see, I'm not using `ng-transclude` but instead appending the cloned element directly somewhere in the DOM.

Comment: And what is the reason not to use `ng-transclude`?

Comment: I've copied this from a tutorial, need to look it up to remeber why exactly they didn't use the ng-transclude.